# Spliting an array into subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I want to break an array into subarrays each with N elements. But one subarray must have the last, suppose 2 elements of previous subarray as its first elements. Can anyone help me solve this problem? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty1I0.png)

Comment: Please add some demo data as well what you have tried so far

Comment: X=[0,9,8,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,8]  I want to break this into sub arrays,  each with 4 elements [[0, 9,8,6][8, 6,1,2][1, 2,3,4][3, 4,5,6][5,6,8,0]]. last 2 elements of 1st sub array is the first 2 elements of 2nd block, this repeats. Finally if the last sub array is not having 4 elements zeros should be padded to make its length 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right but that's the way I'd do that

```
import math

x = [0,9,8,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,8]
N = 4
tail = 2

new_x = [x[:N]]
for i in range(math.ceil((len(x)-N) / (N-tail))):
    new_x.append(new_x[-1][-tail:] + x[N + i*(N-tail): N + (i+1)*(N-tail)])
if len(new_x[-1]) < N:
    new_x[-1] += x[:N-len(new_x[-1])]

print(new_x)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 9, 8, 6], [8, 6, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 8, 0]]
```

Comment: sir, when i run your code in python 2.7 (ubantu) i got an error - range() integer end argument expected, got float. when i used the int function in range(), last block got missing from the output.But i also tried this in google colab,there it worked perfectly.any solution will be appreciated.                                                      Thanks a lot.

Comment: Its because in python 2.7 product of diving two integers is always integer (so its rounding result down) so we need to convert divider or dividend into float like so `range(int(math.ceil((len(x)-N) / float(N-tail))))` so our loop will go desired amount of times.

Comment: sir, why this method fails when there are thousands of elements in x? i used this code to split an array of audio signal values(9000 elements) which includes negative numbers also. can you please help me do this. Thanks

Comment: What's the error, when I test this on 9000 random numbers everything works fine. Could you provide sample of your test data?

Comment: Please add your code and errors to main question, it will be more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: I have added a screenshot in the main question,sir.regret the inconvenience.

Comment: Why you set `tail` to `len(z)-1`? Tail determines amount of last elements of previous list that next list will have at beginning.

Comment: It's the step involved in finding block convolution in digital signal processing..length of the 2nd signal is treated as tail... It's 400-1.these blocks are then individually convoluted with the 2 nd signal.

Comment: Please try to prepare data and code to recreate this error and add it to your question.